# @Autowired null at Run Time

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

In the below code I am using `inAppPurchaseService` to call its function,    but at runtime its showing me `null` when I print `inAppPurchaseService`

```
 public class SubscriptionChecker {

    private static final Logger log      =Logger.getLogger(SubscriptionChecker.class);

   @Autowired
     private EmployerService employerService;

   @Autowired
    private InAppPurchaseService inAppPurchaseService;

   private static final RenewalCheckStrategy STRATEGY_APPLE
    = new AppleRenewalCheckStrategyImpl();

   private static final RenewalCheckStrategy STRATEGY_GOOGLE
    = new GoogleRenewalCheckStrategyImpl();



  public boolean checkSubscription(User user) throws IOException,    HunterException{
  boolean res = false;

   OptedPlan optedPlan = getCurrentSubscription(user);
  switch (optedPlan.getPlanType()){
    case FREE: res = checkFreeSubscription(optedPlan);
      break;
    case PREMIUM: res = checkPremiumSubscription(optedPlan,user);
      break;

    }

    return res;
}

  /**


* 
 * @param optedPlan
 * @return
 */
public boolean checkFreeSubscription(OptedPlan optedPlan ){  
      optedPlan.setPlanExpired(HunterUtil.isPlanExpired(optedPlan.getPlanExpirationDate()));
      optedPlan.setPlanActive(HunterUtil.isPlanActive(optedPlan.getPlanActiveDate()));
      //log.info("checkFreeSubscriptionResponse::  "+(optedPlan.isPlanActive())?(optedPlan.getMaxConnectionCount()>0 && optedPlan.getMaxJobCount()>0):true);
     return(optedPlan.isPlanActive())?(optedPlan.getMaxConnectionCount()>0 || optedPlan.getMaxJobCount()>0):true;


  }

    private boolean checkPremiumSubscription(OptedPlan optedPlan,User user) throws IOException, HunterException{
    boolean res = false;
    Date now = new Date();
   optedPlan.setPlanExpired(HunterUtil.isPlanExpired(optedPlan.getPlanExpirationDate()));
Employer employer=(Employer)user;
//First check stored expiry date
log.info("checkPremiumSubscription:: "+optedPlan.isPlanExpired());
if(optedPlan.isPlanExpired()){
  // If expired, check for renewal
    optedPlan =
    getRenwRenewalCheckStrategy(optedPlan).getRenewal(optedPlan,user);
    employer.setOptedPlan(optedPlan);
    employerService.save(employer);
  if (optedPlan != null){
    // Renewal found: check date and update information in db
    res = optedPlan.getPlanExpirationDate().after(now);
    log.info("checkPremiumSubscriptionFlag:: "+optedPlan.getPlanExpirationDate().after(now));
  }
 }


return res;
}


     private OptedPlan getCurrentSubscription(User user) throws HunterException{
  Employer employer=(Employer)user;

log.info("getCurrentSubscriptionResponse:: "+(HunterUtil.isNull(employer.getOptedPlan())?inAppPurchaseService.setFreePlanInEmployer(new StripeChargeTokenDto("FREE",DeviceType.ANDROID), employer)
        :employer.getOptedPlan()));
return    (HunterUtil.isNull(employer.getOptedPlan())?inAppPurchaseService.setFreePlanInEmployer(new StripeChargeTokenDto("FREE",DeviceType.ANDROID), employer)
        :employer.getOptedPlan());
   }

  private RenewalCheckStrategy getRenwRenewalCheckStrategy(OptedPlan optedPlan){
   RenewalCheckStrategy res = null;
   res =   (optedPlan.getDeviceType().equals(DeviceType.ANDROID))?STRATEGY_GOOGLE:STRATEGY_APPLE;   

   return res;
  }
  }
```

My `inAppPurchaseService` is like

```
  public interface InAppPurchaseService extends   GenericService<BillingDetails> {
      OptedPlan setFreePlanInEmployer(StripeChargeTokenDto stripeChargeTokenDto,Employer employer)throws HunterException;
     String gettingResponseForReceiptValidation(InAppPurchaseReceiptDto inAppPurchaseReceiptDto,Employer employer) throws HunterException;
     JSONObject createRequestForValidation(String     inAppPurchaseReceipt,Employer employer) throws HunterException;
    void receiptForSuccessTransaction(InAppPurchaseReceiptResponse      inAppResponse, Employer employer);
    void updateOptedPlanOfEmployer(InAppPurchaseReceiptResponse      inAppResponse, Employer emp,String productId,DeviceType deviceType) throws      HunterException;
 }
```

Also please note on `InAppPurchaseServiceImpl` I have added `@Service`    annotations in my code.

Comment: what is your MVC config,can you show those?

Comment: you need to add Component annotation for your class that way spring container will be scan and bind into what you want with autowired

Comment: I am only using annotations based no config and annotations I am using are  @EnableAutoConfiguration
SpringBootApplication
EnableMongoAuditing
EnableSwagger2
EnableAsync
EnableScheduling    in my base class

Comment: @mithatkonuk do I have to add Component on SubscriptionChecker class?

Comment: Show the code of `InAppPurchaseServiceImpl` where you use `SubscriptionChecker`

Comment: @dunni in SubscriptionChecker I only autowired InAppPurchaseService while SubscriptionChecker is called by another class and here is the code        Authenticated authAnnotation = (Authenticated) annotation;      if (authAnnotation.subscriptionRequired()){
        if (!subscriptionChecker.checkSubscription(user)){
           throw new UserNotAuthorizedException();
         }
      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top of class of SubscriptionChecker should be `@Component`, because SubscriptionChecker is not initialized by spring context.

Comment: I have added @Component on subscriptionChecker class but its not working

Comment: The SubscriptionChecker class should be under package of SpringBootApplication class.is it?

Answer (score 0):

Your SubscriptionChecker  isn't managed by Spring.

For @Autowired annotation to work you have to annotate that class with either

```
@Component
@Service
@Controller
@Repository
```

Comment: I have already added @Service annotations in my  InAppPurchaseServiceImpl and I think its sufficient to make its service autowired

Comment: yes, that is sufficient to make the service autowired, but you can only autowire it into classes that are also managed by Spring. Thus your SubscriptionChecker also has to have one of the annotations I mentioned